# Why do the weather samples in FetchData seem to get cached for the sample Blazor app?

Tags: json, visual-studio, blazor

The Blazor app in Visual Studio uses a Http.GetFromJsonAsync call to get the data for Weather Forecasts from a json file in wwwroot.

When I change the data in the file, I still see the same data in the table?

When I copy the file, and change the code to use the new filename, I get the changed results.

Is there some caching happening with wwwroot files? I've tried hard refresh, that doesn't make a difference, but changing browser does. I know that Blazor caches the framework files...but is this happening to all wwwroot, how do I change this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetchdata sample page (from new blazorwasm) retrieves data on initialize component:

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
}
```

When you go out of this page and come back, initialize is running again and a request is done.

**But**, because this is a `GET` request, the browser can deliver answer from cache:

[image]

They are some ways to avoid cache on Blazor GET requests, learn about it here: [Bypass HTTP browser cache when using HttpClient in Blazor WebAssembly](https://www.meziantou.net/bypass-browser-cache-using-httpclient-in-blazor-webassembly.htm)

Also, you can use the simple trick to add a random string to query string:

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var randomid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var url_get = $"sample-data/weather.json?{randomid}";
    forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>(url_get);
}
```

[image]

In short, it seems to get cached because **a get request can be cached by browser** and is the browser who retrieve the data.

Comment: What about using CancellationToken and once the Blazor component is removed from the page then we can call canecl metheod to stop the operation!. Can that help to refresh the data ?

Comment: CancellationTolen is not related with cache.